# UITabBarItem appearance -setTitleTextAttributes keeps logging "state = 1 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted"?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

In my AppDelegate implementation file I use these lines of code to set custom fonts and colors of tabBarItems:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

For some (unknown) reason the following messages get logged, one for each tabBarItem:

```
button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateDisabled. state = 1 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
```

Couldn't find anything using the standard search engines, so I seek your help. What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Mine also has the same problem. I think we just ignore it. But its really annoying if you need to see other messages in the console. You may see this thread: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/105017-uitabbaritem-logging-state-1-interpreted-uicontrolstatehighlighted.html

Comment: By reading Camille's answer, I replace "UIControlStateHighlighted" with "UIControlStateSelected" and the message is gone. It looks different to Camille's answer, but my case is for "UITabBarItem" whereas Camille's is for "UIBarButtonItem".

Comment: Wayne Liu, you should post this as an answer imho.
It looks like the console warning really is misleading. For the `titleTextAttributes` on a UITabBar the accepted states seem to be `UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateSelected` and `UIControlStateDisabled`. But not `UIControlStateHighlighted` as the warning suggests.

Answer (score 51):

Just change the "UIControlStateHighlighted" to "UIControlStateSelected". Hope this helps!

Comment: works. It's like they do the same job, then why Apple keeps both?

Comment: I still get the warning

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue because I was using:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I changed it to:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

…and the problem went away. Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean you did the exact opposite of the above answer?